# how to compute the matrix polynomial

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be the matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & \sqrt{2}\\ -\sqrt{2} & -1\\ \end{pmatrix}$$

> Compute the matrix $B = 3A -2A^2 - A^3 -5A^4 + A^6$.

Could any one give me any hint for this one? I have calculated the eigenvalues they are $(1+\sqrt{2}i),(1-\sqrt{2}i)$

Comment: hint: compute directly $A^2$.

Comment: Find a matrix $P$ to diagonalize the matrix. You can then easily add up the diagonialized matrices and then use $P^{-1}$. Or, you can just brute force it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the characteristic polynomial $ch_A(x)=\begin{vmatrix}1-x&\sqrt{2}\\-\sqrt{2}&1-x\end{vmatrix}=(x-1)^2+2=x^2-2x+3$.

Then by [Cayley-Hamilton theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley-Hamilton_theorem) we know that $A^2-2A+3=0$.

So if you divide your polynomial $p(x)$ by $(x^2-2x+3)$ and you get $p(x)=q(x)(x^2-2x+3)+r(x)$, you only need to calculate $r(A)$, i.e., to plug the matrix $A$ into the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

In this example probably the best way is to use  Raymond Manzoni's hint.

In general if $A$ is similar to $C$ with $A=P^{-1}CP$ for some invertible $P$ then for any polynomial $\phi(x)$: $$\phi(A)=P^{-1}\phi(C)P.$$ In your case use that $A$ is similar to $\begin{pmatrix}1+\sqrt{2}&0\\0&1-\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$.
 Also see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#An_application).